# Gnucash Finance::Quote 3 currencies exchange rates

Tags: gnucash

Using Gnucash 3.9 and Finance::Quote 1.47

My business uses TWD as the base currency, but we also have accounts in USD and CAD.

Finance::quote automatically provides exchange rates for TWD/USD and TWD/CAD but not USD/CAD.

I am using the "Fetch Rate" button on a USD to CAD transfer, but it only pulls in the manually entered rate I've provided on Price Database page.

Similarly the Price Database "Get Quotes" button does not pull in USD/CAD.

Is there any way I can automatically get the USD/CAD rate?